# Is there a way to automatically edit wrapped words on find sublime3

Tags: sublimetext, sublimetext3

Good day,

is there a way to automatically edit the found words using ctrl + f in sublime, without clicking the found word.

[image]

its just extra effort if you'll click the word again even though its already high lighted, using a keyboard key would be much easier specially if your always using the search function.

thank you for the tips.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if this makes things easier for you, but you can simply press <kbd>Esc</kbd> when the word is selected, which will bring the focus back to the editor and you can edit the word, and cycle through the next selections using <kbd>F3</kbd> or bring up the find box using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>

Comment: ohh.. I did not thought that it would be that simple :) anyways, thank you very much.. I have been using sublime for quite sometime now and I always find this function not convenient in editing, not to know that there is an easy way to do this. THANK YOU VERY MUCH.